# Error 400 when POST'ing JSON in angularjs + Spark Single Page Application

Tags: angularjs, json, http, single-page-application, spark-java

I'm new to Single Page Application area and I try to develop app using angularjs and Spark framework. I get error 400 bad request when I want to post JSON from my website. Here is code fragment from client side:

```
app.controller('PostTripCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.newTrip = {};
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'http://localhost:4567/trips/add',
        data : $scope.newTrip,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log("ok");
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log($scope.newTrip);
    });

};
});
```

Values that are to be assigned to newTrip are read from appropriate inputs in html file. Here is server-side fragment:

```
post("/trips/add", (req, res) -> {
        String tripOwner = req.queryParams("tripOwner");
        String startDate = req.queryParams("startDate");
        String startingPlace = req.queryParams("startingPlace");
        String tripDestination = req.queryParams("tripDestination");
        int tripPrice = Integer.parseInt(req.queryParams("tripPrice"));
        int maxNumberOfSeats = Integer.parseInt(req.queryParams("maxNumberOfSeats"));
        int seatsAlreadyOccupied = Integer.parseInt(req.queryParams("seatsAlreadyOccupied"));

        tripService.createTrip(tripOwner, startDate, startingPlace, tripDestination, tripPrice, maxNumberOfSeats,
                seatsAlreadyOccupied);
        res.status(201);
        return null;

    } , json());
```

At the end I obtain error 400 bad request. It is strange for me that when I want to see output on the console

```
System.out.println(req.queryParams());
```

I get json array of objects with values written by me on the website. However, when I want to see such output

```
System.out.println(req.queryParams("tripOwner"));
```

I get null. Does anyone have idea what is wrong here?

Comment: can you add a log of the request body from the client, and another log of System.out.println(req.queryParams()) so we can compare?

Comment: System.out.println(req.body()); output: {"tripOwner":"Ding","startDate":"1-01-2016","startingPlace":"Zhengzhou","tripDestination":"Pekin","tripPrice":300,"maxNumberOfSeats":4,"seatsAlreadyOccupied":2}

System.out.println(req.queryParams()); output: []

System.out.println(req.queryParams("tripOwner")); output: null

Comment: So you aren't actually getting any query params at the server then according to those logs. Your log of req.queryParams() appears to be an empty array, indicating that nothing was received. Have you checked the network tab of your browser and looked at the request body to verify that your POST does actually contain the JSON body you logged?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why...

Comment: I'll preface this by saying I know nothing about Spark. Is there any chance that queryParams is made for checking URL params, while you are sending a request body (and no url params)?

Comment: I don't think so. According to Spark documentation request.queryParams();  should return the query param list, while request.queryParams("FOO"); should return value of FOO query param

Comment: Right, but you aren't using url query params. You are passing a request body. Those are not the same thing. Passing a json object is not query params. Query params would be variables and values in the url like https://www.someapi.com/endpoint?queryparam1=true&queryparam2=false

Comment: Actually I tried to use query params in this app but I'm stuck now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to cope with that using another approach. I used Jackson and ObjectMapper according to Spark documentantion. Thanks for your answers.

You can see more about that here: https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/04/03/spark-lombok-jackson-reduce-boilerplate.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that you are sending data to your Spark webservice with the `'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` header. Try sending it as `'Content-Type' : 'application/json'` instead, then in your Java code declare a String to receive `req.body()`, you'll see all your data in there.

Note: When you try to acces your data like this `req.queryParams("tripOwner");` you're not accessing post data, but you're seeking for a get parameter called tripOwner, one that could be sent like this `http://localhost:8080/trips/add?tripOwner=MyValue`.

Comment: Thank you! I could not figure out how to put that into words yesterday. +1

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using postman to post a request to your server and see if it works. Try a different content type too. Try using curl and play with the various headers you are sending. 400 suggests the wrong data is being sent or expected data is missing or the data is the wrong type but based on your code you've provided I can see nothing wrong (but see below).

When your server receives a request log all request headers being received and see what changing them does. If it works in postman then you can change your client code to mirror the headers postman is using.

Does your spark server validate the data being sent before your controller code is hit? If so ensure you are adhering to all validation rules

Also on looking at your code again your client is sending the data in the post data but your server is expecting the data in the query string and not in the post data?

What happens if your server just sends a 201 response and does nothing else? Does your client get a 201 back? If so it suggests the hook up is working but there is something wrong with the code before you return a 201, build it up slowly to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably just needed to enable CORS(Cross-origin resource sharing) in your Spark Server, which would have allowed you to access the REST resources outside the original domain of the request.

```
    Spark.options("/*", (request,response)->{

    String accessControlRequestHeaders = request.headers("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        if (accessControlRequestHeaders != null) {
            response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", accessControlRequestHeaders);
        }

    String accessControlRequestMethod = request.headers("Access-Control-Request-Method");
        if(accessControlRequestMethod != null){
            response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", accessControlRequestMethod);
        }

    return "OK";
});

Spark.before((request,response)->{
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
});
```

Read more about pre-flighted requests [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).